# [] overloading c++ array of functions not allowed

Tags: c++, node.js, graph, overloading

Hello im trying to create a graph and im working on my function prototypes, on my [] operator overload function im getting the following error:array of functions not allowed here is my prototype:

```
BinaryTree& ooperator[](int vertex);
```

binary tree is a binary tree class what do i need to change to get this to work

Answer (score 6):

You've misspelled `operator` as `ooperator`. Oops!

```
BinaryTree& operator[](int vertex);
//          ^
```